# discord.py how do I get a bot to send a message when a specific user types?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to get my bot to type when a specific member types. How would I be able to use their ID, or get their discord ID and allow the bot to use it to detect that they are the author of the message

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do so is to use the ID of that user as reference

If you have developer mode activated on your personal discord client, right click on a user and click "copy the ID" (or something like that)

Now, on the [discord.py API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html), you can find everything you need about objets and their attributes.

the `Message` class has a `author` attribute which is of class `Member`. And the `Member` class has a `id` attribute, which is an integer. You should write inside the `on_message` method:

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author.id == id_of_the_user_as_integer:
        # Do what you want
```

Comment: I was looking on the discord py api thing and I couldnt find what I was looking for. Guess I missed it. while you're here, what does "@client.event" do? and do I need to use it for every feature I add?

Comment: I'm not sure about things using the `@` stuff, sorry. In the discord API, the left side features all the different objects. Find `message` in it and click it, you'll see all its attributes. You'll need this if you want to extract further information from the message that the bot reads, like the channel it was sent in, whether the author is a bot, or if the message contains mentions

Comment: Why did you pass "self"? It's not used in the code anywhere

Comment: That's because of the way that my bot is built. `on_message` is a method within the `Client` class, so it needs the `self` argument. But I've seen it can be done otherwise, I don't know much about that